# Divide by Zero on Average Time Excel

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I'm getting a #DIV/0 when calculating the average time from a range of cells.

A copy of the file can be found here;

http://www44.zippyshare.com/v/5ZlxD44N/file.html

I have literally no idea why this is happening, nor can I seem to find a way around this.

I have checked the formatting of the cells, tried to re save the file, pull the data on to a new page. Nothing seems to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the data in `A1:C10` is stored as text (by default text is left alligned and cell's display doesn't change when you change formatting). To convert it to time values:

- enter `1` in any empty cell
- copy this cell
- select `A1:C10`, choose `Paste special->Multiply`
- format the range back to time format

Your sheet is set to manual calculation, so make sure to recalculate the sheet with `F9` or switch it to automatic.

Alternatively you can convert text to time inside array formula (confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A10*1)
```